# iPad image quality on zoom in

Tags: ipad, zooming, image-quality

Good morning,

I have an a series of floorplans that I need to load on the iPad. The floorplans are pretty large high-quality images. In order to control the look and feel of the application I need to restrict the width of the image to 1020px. I still however need to be able to zoom-in and have a very clear image. The images look great when zooming in on a browser at a desktop. However, it looks terrible when zooming in on the iPad.

This is the tag I am using to load the image:

img src="/files/floorplans/{!$floorplan.ID}/{!$FloorplanID}/{!$floorplan.FileName}" width="1020"

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, well 1020 pixels is relatively low for zooming (it's the same resolution as a Tube Television :), when you say, "control the look and feel of the application" do you mean performance when loading the images or something else, could you elaborate?

Also are you viewing the images on an iPad 2 or 3? you probably know the iPad 3's retina display has a vastly better resolution.

I can only add to make sure that your UIImageView's size is the same as the images'

```
// Something like
UIImage* image = // your image from url
UIImageView* imageView = [UIImageView initWithImage:etc..];

imageView.image.size = image.size;
```

Also, if I remember correctly, if your image view is embedded in a scroll view (which is likely) then it's frame will have to be sized as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :) I am using an iPad 2 for testing, but the images are very fuzzy when zooming in. I don't know what to do because they look great when zooming on a browser at a desktop. I want to make sure the image is contained within a 1020 wide div. Thank you again, I really appreciate your feedback

Comment: Yes. 1000-ish pixels wide is not much at all. Its just enough to fill the entire width of the screen in landscape. Putting the image in a scroll view is a good fit. Only when the image becomes so big that you can't load it all into memory at once would you need to look into other solutions like tiling the image